# Can you implement Native mobile notifications in PWAs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, push-notification, progressive-web-apps

I'm making a todo list app with react and firebase. I've set it up to be also used as a PWA so to be used like a native mobile app. (see image below)

[image: iphone]

Now i was wondering whether I can implement native mobile notifications like in IOS or Android with a PWA.

Comment: You can since iOS 16.4